# CoreAudio AudioQueue i/o redirect to/from phone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I've been reading up on some of the iPhone audio services in considering an audio recording/playback app, but ideally I'd like to be able to use the other end of a phone connection as inputs and outputs, i.e. remote speaker and remote microphone via cellular (or VoIP, but for now cellular's the question), when it's on, as input and output targets for redirect...  I can't seem to find any documentation saying this is possible or impossible...  obviously apple phone app is closed source, and I can't modify it, but can I just hook up to either or both of its streams?  Does it make any difference if it's a call initiated by my app or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible to reroute the audio source and sink of a phone call on iPhone. It is possible on other smartphone platforms.

You could route the local mic and speaker over a network connection that would use the default network route (either WiFi or cellular data) to achieve your goals.

Comment: Thanks Roger....  sounds pretty clearcut, though I didn't know the term "sink" for audio output, makes sense I guess...  Which platforms do you know it's possible on out of curiosity?  Also, is the issue that Apple forbids it for official App releases, or it just can't be done?  Odd limitation...

Comment: Hm, So I may have spoken out of turn. I should have said I "believe" it's possible on other platforms. I was thinking SymbianOS and Android.

I'm not sure if you could do this in a Jailbroken phone. I see no reason why not.